# Why training baseline of REINFORCE by MSE?

Tags: machine-learning, variance, optimization, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

In following references

```
 [1] V. Mnih et al., "Recurrent Models of Visual Attention", NIPS, 2014
 [2] http://torch.ch/blog/2015/09/21/rmva.html
 [3] M. Ranzato et al., "Sequence level training with Recurrent Neural Network", ICLR, 2016
```

they applied REINFORCE algorithm to train RNN.

To reduce variance of the gradient, they subtract 'baseline' from sum of future rewards for all time steps. 
According to Appendix A-2 of

[4]. W. Zaremba et al., "Reinforcement Learning Neural Turing Machines", arXiv, 2016

this baseline is chosen as expected future reward given previous states/actions.

My question is training method to get 'baseline'.
They train 'baseline' at each time by linear regression (i.e. objective = Mean Square Error) which takes hidden state of RNN as input. How come this training method make sense? Is there anyone to provide relevant reference?

I really appreciate for your comments.

Answer (score 4):

So the reason you want a baseline is that $R_\tau$ can be very different from one episode to another *under the policy you are training* (equation no 3 in the paper). Subtracting a baseline from that return helps reducing the variance and stabilizing the algorithm. See for example [John Schulman's MLSS Lecture](https://youtu.be/oPGVsoBonLM?t=26m52s) or David Silver's lecture on [policy gradient methods](https://youtu.be/KHZVXao4qXs?t=1h6m33s).

When training policy gradient methods the baseline can be whatever approximates best the expected reward onward from the step you are in. A natural baseline is the state value function, the value of being in that state $V(s)$. Usually these functions are learned by parametric estimators (linear function approximators, neural networks, etc.). More on the general theory of using baselines in policy gradient methods you can find [here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1713-policy-gradient-methods-for-reinforcement-learning-with-function-approximation.pdf).

In the paper you linked they are using a separate LSTM that learns to predict the expected episodic return from that step onward, $R_\tau$ so it is only natural that the objective to be minimized is the squared mean error between the actual return $R_\tau$ and the value predicted by the baseline LSTM, $b_\tau$.

The features the baseline LSTM is using are the full tape at the first time step and then the exact input the RL-LSTM is receiving at each step which is a fairly complex statistic (past actions, current memory, current input, hidden state of RL-LSTM). If you are asking if this is a sufficient statistic to predict the episodic return $R_\tau$, well, it seems to be working :). For example a similar baseline was learned in this [attention model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6247v1.pdf) + [implementation](http://torch.ch/blog/2015/09/21/rmva.html).

Comment: The link to learning more about baseline reduction is broken. Please edit it. Thanks :)